# ANSI Escape code like [?25h in Console? Why?

Tags: python, openpyxl

i wrote a small programm for excel automation and everything works fine, but i've got these characters ([?25h) while execution in my console.

I added my code but dont be that hard, i am new :D

Does anybody has a clue what this mean...google didnt help anyway :( [image]

```py
# from typing import Counter
import openpyxl as xl
import os
# import time
from progress.bar import Bar
import warnings

str_path_to_dir = input('Enter the path of the directory where the files are:')
which_to_edit = input('Enter the sheet name:')     #'Cover page'

filenames = []

# bar = Bar('Progress:', max = len(filenames))

def Amount():
    global times_to_do
    times_to_do = int(input('How many cells do you want to change?'))
    global counter
    counter = 0
    while counter < times_to_do:
        counter += 1
        Files()
  
def Directory():
    path_to_dir = os.path.join(os.getcwd(), str_path_to_dir)
    os.chdir(path_to_dir)
    directory = os.fsencode(path_to_dir)    # C:\Users\MU015U\Desktop\Code\01_Lists - muss noch gemacht werden damit user eingabe funktioniert!!!
    for file in os.listdir(directory):
        filename = os.fsdecode(file)
        if filename.endswith(('.xlsx', '.xlsm', '.xls', '.xml')):
            filenames.append(filename)
        else:
            print('try to change file extension!')

def Files():
    location = input('Enter the location:')          #'C48'
    text_to_write = input('Enter the text that should be written:')     #'just try it!!!'
    with Bar(f'Progress {counter}/{times_to_do}:', max = len(filenames)) as bar:
        for file in filenames:
            book = xl.load_workbook(filename=file)
            sheet_name = book.get_sheet_by_name(which_to_edit)
            sheet_name[location] = str(text_to_write)
            book.save(os.fsdecode(file))
            bar.next()

        
Directory()
Amount()

input('Finished - Check the files! -- Press Enter to Exit...')
```

Comment: please share your sample code

Comment: ANSI escape code?

Comment: Whatever terminal you are using doesn't appear to recognize `CSI ? 25 h`, which would show the cursor. (My guess is that `Bar` uses its counterpart, `CSI ? 25 l` to hide the cursor while it is displaying the progress bar. It was probably displayed as well, but overwritten by the bar itself.)

Comment: (CSI is short for "control sequence indicator"; it's the two-byte sequence `<esc> [`, where `<esc>` is displayed as the small block character in your screen shot.)

Comment: `? 25 h` is a so-called *private* sequence; the ANSI standard reserved a set of valid sequences for different terminal manufacturers to use as they like. You can be using an ANSI-compatible terminal without it having to do anything specific for `CSI ? 25 h`; your terminal appears to just ignore it and display it literally.

Comment: Thanks @chepner for the info... i try to find a solution within my code :D